# Как работать с DownloadManager?

Tags: java, android, файлы

Файл передаётся между устройствами по локальной сети по средствам сокетов.

> Файлы передаются и всё работает, но они не появляются в системной
>   папке "Загрузки".

Подсказали, что надо использовать `DownloadManager` иначе файл там не появится. Как я понял из документации Android этот класс используется только для получения файла с сервера, но как же тогда быть мне? Заранее спасибо, надеюсь на конструктивные ответы.

Comment: А почему бы просто не сохранять файл в `/storage/sdcard0/downloads/`?

Comment: я и так получаю файл через этот путь, но в системной папке "Загрузки" файл не появляется(только через сторонний проводник) в этом то и всё дело.